# Is there any difference between "by means of" and "with the help of"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage

Can we use the phrase "**by means of**" instead of "**with the help of**", and vice versa?

Example: I wrote above text **by means of / with the help of** a keyboard.

Comment: FWIW, ngrams for [means/help of a friend](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+of+a+friend%2Cby+means+of+a+friend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) -- usage seems to have changed mid 19th century. [A hammer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=help+of+a+hammer%2Cby+means+of+a+hammer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3), albeit a tool, appears to have been a helpful sort of thing rather than a means to an end, although its helpfulness has been in a steady decline..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"By means of" is generally used when describing a tool or a mechanism. "With the help of" is more often used to refer to a source of assistance.

So, "I typed this comment by means of a keyboard." Yes. "I typed this comment with the help of a keyboard." I'd say no. The keyboard did not assist you, it was a tool. "I typed this comment with the help of my friend Alice." If Alice provided advice, or assisted you in using the keyboard, yes.

For the most part, I think people use "by means of" when discussing an inanimate object and "with the help of" when talking about a person or people. But that's not a hard and fast rule. "I sent this message by means of Bob" might be considered a reasonable sentence, if Bob was the messenger. I think it's awkward, but possible. "I found my way with the help of a GPS" works, if you're thinking of the GPS as assisting you in the task.

Comment: Just to add, for inanimate objects, I'd say it would come down to primary vs secondary tools — "I drew the line by means of a pen", "I drew a straight line with the help of a ruler".

Comment: @anotherdave Yes, "with the help of a ruler" sounds right to me. I'm just going by a fuzzy intuition here, hard to say why "help of a GPS" and "help of a ruler" "sound right" while "I drove with the help of a car" and "I wrote with the help of a pen" definitely do not.

Comment: I think it down to the use of the tool in the action. You could not drive without a car — it's the means by which you are completing the task :) You could drive without a GPS, though you might get lost more, so in this case it's helping you to get the task done more quickly/easily.

Comment: @anotherdave Sure, I get your point, and it sounds plausible. I'm not disagreeing, I just don't want to express whole-hearted agreement without thinking it through further. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Often, but not always. Saying, for example, that you finished a report "by means of my friend Jerry" sounds strange and rather unpleasant. But saying you finished the same report "with the help of Jerry" is perfectly natural and clear.

I can't immediately think of a similar example for the converse, so you should be able to go with the rule of thumb that "by means of" is a narrower phrase that mostly belongs in a sentence when you're referring to something that's essentially mechanistic or impersonal: a tool, not a human or animal.

Answer (score 1):

**"by means of"** means **"through the use of"**. thus the difference is **"through the use of"** vs **"with the help of"**. further, **"through the use of"** is certainly akin to **"facilitated by"** and near **"because of"**.

hence, **"by means of"** is a deterministic relationship, as in **"it is done this way because i used this thing."**

"I **typed** this comment through the use of a keyboard." yes, because keyboards type things.

however,

"I **wrote** the above text by means of a keyboard." no, because keyboards don't exclusively 'write'; they frigging type.

but

"I **wrote** the above text with the help of a keyboard." yes, because typing helps in the process of writing -- but doesn't make it so. most authors use keyboards to help them write their books.